# Importing pandas.io.data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am following along with this tutorial: https://pythonprogramming.net/data-analysis-python-pandas-tutorial-introduction/

He suggests the following import:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
```

so that I can implement:

```
df = web.DataReader("XOM", "yahoo", start, end)
```

However, this is for Python 2.7 and I am using Python3. I have Googled this question and found some results, but can't make it work. Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

As mentioned by wilkas, now you might need to do

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
```

---

I am assuming that you are using the latest version of the package. Check out the newest documentation at https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Let me quote the documentation:

> ```
> Usage
> ```
>
> Starting in 0.19.0, pandas no longer supports pandas.io.data or
>   pandas.io.wb, so you must replace your `imports from pandas.io` with
>   those `from pandas_datareader`:

```
from pandas.io import data, web # <- Don't use these Now.
from pandas_datareader import data, web  # <- use this.
```

Thus, your import statement should be

```
from pandas_datareader import web
```

Then you can implement

```
f = web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end)
```

See their document to use Yahoo data from [HERE](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#yahoo-finance)

Comment: You should update this to `import pandas_datareader.data as web` now.

Comment: Thanks for the update @wilkas